# Constructing a waterfall algorithm from multiple columns in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a multi-column data frame and I wish to implement a waterfall style algorithm that takes the first column if it is present, then looks at the second if it is not, and if that is not present takes the value in the third column, and so on, and if missing in the last column takes a default value (say zero). I have a way of doing this involving adding up a series of vector operations (see below) but it doesn't seem to scale to more columns very well. And, of course, I could do it with nested loops through rows (very unpythonic -- right?).

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape((5,3)),index=['a','b','c','d','e'],columns=['X','Y', 'Z'])
#Make some missing values
frame['X'].ix[0:2] = None
frame['Y'].ix[1:4] = None
frame['Z'].ix[3:5] = None
#This is my kludgy waterfall for the three column case.
frame['Waterfall'] = frame['X'].fillna(0) + frame['Y'].fillna(0) * frame['X'].isnull() + frame['Z'].fillna(0) * (frame['X'].isnull() & frame['Y'].isnull())
```

I am hoping for a solution to this problem that scales well to waterfalls of arbitrary length. If it could be more Pythonic that would be great. Ideally, it would be a function that takes an ordered list of column labels a dataframe as an argument and returns the desired values.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `None` as your missing data value. That forces all your columns to the `object` dtype, which will be slow. Use `nan` instead (this makes everything `doubles` so just be careful with floating point stuff.

I'd use the `bfill` method for `fillna()`:

```
In [26]: frame.fillna(method='bfill', axis=1)['X'].fillna(0)
Out[26]: 
a     1
b     5
c     6
d     9
e    12
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

performance:

```
In [27]: %timeit frame['X'].fillna(0) + frame['Y'].fillna(0) * frame['X'].isnull() + frame['Z'].fillna(0) * (frame['X'].isnull() & fra
me['Y'].isnull())

1000 loops, best of 3: 776 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit frame.fillna(method='bfill', axis=1)['X']
10000 loops, best of 3: 138 µs per loop
```

Comment: But in general we won't want to fill from all the columns, nor will frame order be the waterfall order. Would you use fillna on a subframe constructed to have the right order?

Comment: Call `.fillna(0)` at the end for the case where an entire row is NaN. Why won't that be in the correct order?

Comment: maybe OP wants a reduce over ``combine_first``?

Comment: Because in my real problem, my data frame has 50+ columns and the order in the frame is not the waterfall order (because the frame comes from someone else's data).

Comment: Reorder the frame ahead of time. Make a list of the columns that's in the order you want it, `cols`. Then just set `frame = frame[cols]`.

Comment: That doesn't help with all the other columns in the frame not in the waterfall. I guess I could create frame2 = frame[cols], do the infilling, then set frame['Waterfall'] = frame2['Waterfall'], but that must have performance overhead too.